# Parsing string into Time format JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, datetime, time

I have the following time format `2h 34m 22s` and I'm parsing it as `02:34:22` using this code:

```
const splitterArray = '2h 34m 22s'.split(' ');

let h = '00', m = '00', s = '00';

splitterArray.forEach(val => {
    if (val.includes('h')) {
        h = val.replace('h', '');
    } else if (val.includes('m')) {
        m = val.replace('m', '');
    }
    else if (val.includes('s')) {
        s = val.replace('s', '');
    }
});

console.log(`${h}:${m}:${s}`);
```

This also handles the case when there's only minutes and seconds, or only hours and seconds or only hours and minutes.

Just checking if there's a better way to do it like a library or so (maybe to accept days too).

Comment: Is the time string always in that format or do you have it as a date string / object at some point prior to it being converted to this '2h 34m 22s' format? If you have the necessary date string / object, you could format using date-fns or momentjs

Comment: @ElbertBae always like this .. could include days too (2d 22h 33m 12s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match in wanted order and get the result with colons.

```js
function convert(string) {
    return Array
        .from('hms', p => (string.match(new RegExp(`\\d+(?=${p})`))?.[0] || '') .padStart(2, '0'))
        .join(':');
}

console.log(convert('2h 34m 22s'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the moment library. it has plenty of examples and documentation for all of your time formatting and parsing needs:

https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Momentjs has been deprecated. See https://momentjs.com/docs/